# With tkinter, is there a way to hide numerous widgets if place() method was used?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having difficulty with one specific part of my menu code. I used the place() method for more specific placement of buttons and widgets on the main screen.

Is there any way to hide all of the main menu button and label widgets? The grid() method seems to have a really intuitive way to hide a large amount of widgets using grid_forget() or pack_forget(). Does place_forget() have any variability when it comes to hiding more than just that specific label?

Code Example:

```
### Menu navigation to Training page
def createTrainingPage(event):
    event.widget.place_forget()


#######################
### Widget Creation ###
#######################

### Buttons

TrainingButton = Button(text="Training", foreground="blue", font="bold")
TrainingButton.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.31, anchor=W)
TrainingButton.bind('<Button-1>', createTrainingPage)


    ### I want the createTrainingPage() method to 'erase' 
    ### the menu and create the next page. But it only erases the one
    ### widget the bind() function is attached to. Thoughts?


QuizzesButton = Button(text="Quizzes", foreground="blue", font="bold")
QuizzesButton.place(relx=0.07, rely=0.51, anchor=W)


TrainerButton = Button(text="Management", foreground="blue", font="bold")
TrainerButton.place(relx=0.038, rely=0.71, anchor=W)



### Labels

# Bell Bank img logo
LogoLabel = ttk.Label(image=renderedLogo)
LogoLabel.place(relx=0.025, rely=.1, anchor=W)


TrainingLabel = ttk.Label(prog, text="Training To-Do, Scheduling, etc.", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
TrainingLabel.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.31, anchor=W)


QuizzesLabel = ttk.Label(prog, text="Quiz Scores, Performance, etc.", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
QuizzesLabel.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.51, anchor=W)


TrainerLabel = ttk.Label(prog, text="Trainer Admin: Course, Roster and Training Mgmt", foreground="blue", background="lightgray")
TrainerLabel.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.71, anchor=W)
```

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

Comment: I am curious what the ***"really intuitive way to hide a large amount of widgets using grid_forget() or pack_forget()"***.

Answer (score 1):

The `place_forget()` method works almost identically to the `forget_pack()` and `forget_grid()` methods - they all operate on a widget and essentially "hide" that widget. The choice of which one to use is based on which geometry manager was used to display the widget.

so to hide some menu buttons (or any set of buttons) you can do something like:

```py
menu_buttons = [...]  # (bunch of ttk or tkinter Buttons)

for button in menu_buttons:
    button.place_forget()
```